# An extension of change of variables in double (and $n$-?) integrals - second-order Jacobian?

Tags: integration, tensors

I'm aware that there are many, many questions regarding changing variables in double and triple integrals. The equation that typically pops up in textbooks is
\begin{align}
\iint\limits_{R}f\left(x,y\right)\:dA&=\iint\limits_{S}f\left(g\left(u,v\right),h\left(u,v\right)\right)\:\left|J_{u,v}^{x,y}\right|\:du\:dv,\tag{1}
\end{align}
and here I am using the "short hand" notation
\begin{align}
J_{u,v}^{x,y}=\left|\frac{\partial\left(x,y\right)}{\partial\left(u,v\right)}\right|=\det\begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\[.5em]\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{vmatrix}.
\end{align}
This is great, and I feel as though I have a firm understanding of where it comes from and why it works. But now let's talk tensors.

Does there exist such a thing as the second-order Jacobian? I'm aware of the Hessian matrix, but that is for a single function of two variables (or more). If so, might it look like what I have drawn below, a rank-$3$ tensor containing all of the second-order partial derivatives of our functions?

[image]

It looks like the combination of two Hessian matrices thrown into one.

Now another question:

If such a thing exists, what would happen if we used this second-order Jacobian in $\left(1\right)$? Perhaps it is linked to the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, but over two integrals instead?